# Access relation table after converting collection to array

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to keep access to relation tables after using `toArray()` function when getting results from database?

```
$db_results = TableA::orderBy('order')->get()->toArray();
$db_results = array_slice($db_results, $parameter_number);
foreach($db_results as $db_result) {
   if($db_result['user' /* it's connected with user table over use_id */]) continue;
   //do_something;
}
```

The point is that once collection is turned into array, I can access only to columns which exist in a table.

Comment: you can use select()

Comment: I have changed my question a little bit. Didn't want to get the attribute, but the row from another table which is connected with this one over foreign key. I can't use selecte() since the value I need is not column in my table

Comment: After toarray() you will not able to get relational records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eager loading to preload all relations when you perform your query

```
TableA::with(['name_of_relation_to_eager_load','relation_1', 'relation_2' 'relation_X'])
    ->orderBy('order')->get()->toArray();
```